# Resolve the same DNS name to different IPs depending on client IP network

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip

Is it possible to setup DNS server (Win2k8) thus the same DNS name (an A record) is being resolved to different IPs depending on some option.

E.g. example.com for clients from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.1, for clients from internet - to some inet IP?

P.S.
As far as I know such approach name on BIND is 'views'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server DNS does not have views. It is recommended that you set up separate hardware to cover the private and the public sides.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in BIND this is indeed called "views".

I honestly don't know whether Microsoft's DNS server can do it.  BIND runs quite happily on Windows systems these days, though.

Answer (score 1):

If setting up BIND on your Windows box, or having two separate machines is too much effort/cost - you may want to consider destination NATing the internal machines using iptables or similar.  The beauty of this type of solution is if you already have a *nix firewall in place (and you really *should* have a *nix firewall in place ;) ), no extra machine would be required...  More info:

http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html